# return self.user as foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with foreignkeys. For this model I want to set the 'def **str**' as the user.

I have done this

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Rosters(models.Model):
        place = models.ForeignKey('Places')
        position = models.ForeignKey('Positions', blank=True, null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='roster')
        validfrom = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        validto = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user
```

This will fetch username and show in admin pages. But when I try to create a new Roster. I get a TypeError ***__str__ returned non-string (type User)***

I can remove the 'def **str**...' and create a Roster with no problem. But each Roster shows as Object in admin pages. So I can add back the 'def **str**..' to see the usernames of each roster.

I want them to always display as usernames. And I can't figure out why it's not working when I'm adding rosters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your error show:

```
TypeError __str__ returned non-string (type User)
```

The `__str__` method should return a `str`, and here, you are returning an object (`User`).

You should return `return self.user.__str__` instead (The `str` representation of the user).

Answer (score 7):

You need to refer to the specific field within 'User' you want to display.
Try:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: `.username` can be replaced with any attribute the user model has. i.e email, firstname, lastname etc

Answer (score 2):

you can only return string from `__str__` not user which is an object.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to show the attribute of the user that you wish to display

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.user
```

should return any of the following (or similar)

```
return str(self.user)
return self.user.get_username()
return self.user.get_full_name()
```